# Non-static member initialization of char array with brace gives an error in gcc while not in clang

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Consider following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    char name[40] = { "Blank" }; // note the braces here
public:
    const char *getName() { return name; }
};

int main()
{
    A a;

    std::cout << a.getName() << std::endl;
}
```

It gives an error in `gcc` (latest version `5.2.0`):

```
prog.cpp:5:28: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]
  char name[40] = { "Blank" };
                            ^
```

But it's not the case for `clang`, that compiles it flawlessly with `-std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall`.

Is it really incorrect to put braces for non-static initializer here?

AFAIR it doesn't matter if braces are present or not. For instance, the definition of array, such as:

```
char text[] = "some text";
```

is equivalent to:

```
char text[] = { "some text" };
```

Comment: isn't it the same compiler contraption that allows us to initialize boost::array aggregate with only one brace depth instead of two ?

Comment: Wouldn't `{ "some text"}` initialize an array of strings, such as `char arrayOfStrings[][] = { "some text"};` with the first element containing a pointer to `"some text"`?

Comment: @muXXmit2X That was my first thought too but as the question pointed, it doesn't change anything if you do it inside a function.

Comment: It appears to be a gcc bug as this should be allowed. It seems to work if you eliminate the braces.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Character_arrays

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the standard is not very clear in my opinion, but I would say that CLang is right :

8.5.1 says :

§2 : *When an aggregate is initialized by an initializer list, as specified in 8.5.4, the elements of the initializer list
are taken as initializers for the members of the aggregate, in increasing subscript or member order.* That is gcc interpretation : name is an array, there is a brace-init-list so first element of the array (a char) is initialized with the char array => error

But 8.5.2 explicitely says : *An array of narrow character type ... can be initialized by a narrow string literal ... **or by an appropriately-typed string literal enclosed in braces*** (emphasize mine)

My interpretation is that the standard consideres char arrays as special enough to explicitely allow a string literal enclosed in braces as valid even if it defeats 8.5.1 §2

Answer (score 8):

The code is valid, and is now accepted by GCC trunk. I think it was fixed by [PR 65815 brace elision doesn't work in NSDMI](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65815)

Answer (score 4):

From the C++ standard working draft [n4527](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4527.pdf)  [dcl.init]. An  initialization can be written like :

Initializers

> ```
> initializer:
>   brace-or-equal-initializer
>   ( expression-list )
>
> brace-or-equal-initializer:
>   = initializer-clause
>   braced-init-list
>
> initializer-clause:
>   assignment-expression
>   braced-init-list
> initializer-list:
>   initializer-clause...opt
>   initializer-list,initializer-clause...opt
>
> braced-init-list:
>   {initializer-list,opt}
>   { }
> ```

A Class member declaration

> ```
> member-declarator:
>   declarator virt-specifier-seq opt pure-specifier opt
>   declarator brace-or-equal-initializer opt
> ```

From what I read it seems like gcc does not meet the standard. Because the class member initialization using the braces is accepted by the standard.

Comment: Which of these is relevant to this example? `brace-or-equal-initializer`?

Comment: Both. The first one apply whenever a variable is initialized, the second one is specialized for class member declaration.

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the question at all, since `gcc` is not reporting a syntax error. It accepts the braces, but apparently takes it to mean that the first following expression initialises the first element of the array, whence a type error is reported in converting a character pointer to a single character. Whether this follows the standard or not I don't know, but in any case cannot be deduced from the syntax rules you cited.

Comment: The syntax rules I quoted show no ban about initializing your variable with a string literal between the braces.

Comment: Just because something is syntactically valid doesn't mean that it's valid C++ code. This doesn't answer the question at all, -1.

Answer (score 2):

fwiw, `g++` has several problems with brace-based initialisation and/or constructor-calling, including some reported recently.

However (editing), as Jonathan has rightly pointed out, most (all?) of these can be worked around easily. I have had success substituting the old parenthesis syntax into affected bits of code.

It would be educational to hear of a situation where this couldn't be done, but thankfully I've not personally found one, so `g++` remains eminently usable for me (with comments explaining why I use the old syntax in certain odd places!)

Comment: All of those bugs have simple workarounds, so yes there are other bugs that people are working on first (like the compiler cashing on valid code, or lambdas doing the wrong thing). And the OP's bug is already fixed.

Comment: Oh, for sure. With the brace-related quirks I've come across so far, it usually suffices to use parentheses instead, and thankfully, I've not yet found a situation where this can't be done - it's hard for me to imagine one. Apologies: my post seemed a little harsher than I really meant to be. :)

Comment: No problem, I was commenting more for other readers who might use your answer as anti-GCC fuel ;) I hadn't seen your https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63151 report, I'll confirm it now (or close as a dup if you're right that it might be)

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! I definitely don't want to do anything except promote GCC. The mentioned ticket wasn't mine and is already confirmed - but 66847 could always use confirmation! :D That's the one that's potentially a dupe (and has overly dramatic wording - guess I was cranky that night)

Comment: Oops, yes, 66847 is what I meant ... must have pasted the wrong URL

Comment: I figured. Thanks a lot for having a look!